# How to get shortest path using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am using networkx to find the shortest path passing through all the nodes in a graph. This is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=10)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=20)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=30)
G.add_edge('a', 'e', weight=40)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', weight=70)
G.add_edge('b', 'd', weight=80)
G.add_edge('b', 'e', weight=90)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=50)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=60)
G.add_edge('d', 'e', weight=100)

nx.shortest_path(G,source='a',target='a')
```

I am trying to find the shortest path from 'a' to 'a' and my but i get ['a'] as the output. My understanding is that the way i entered my code i am not allowed to go from 'a' to 'a' so why am i getting this output? How do i specify that i cannot go from 'a' to 'a'.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you **sure**? With above code it gives `0` as output. You are not using `shortest_path` (*you will get as above which is correct*) but `shortest_path_length` in above code.

Comment: @student oops i just changed it but i still get the undesired output

Comment: The shortest path from `a` to `a` does not go through any other nodes.  It's already at `a` when it starts.

Comment: The shortest path ends on start node `a` which is reasonable. Are you confused on that?

Comment: Try `source='a', target='b'` and hopefully you'll get a bit more intuition for what the `shortest_path` commands are doing.

Comment: Then, look up the traveling salesman problem to see why networkx doesn't have a command to do what you're trying.

Comment: @joel thanks i will look into that.